# How am I supposed to show I used a technology on Careers 2.0 if the tag doesn't exist?

Tags: discussion, tags, jobs

My first job involved some scripting of devices using the serial port and our technology of choice was ProComm Plus.  The company that made that software ([Datastorm Technologies, Inc.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datastorm_Technologies,_Inc.)) was bought out (by [Quarterdeck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarterdeck_Office_Systems) which was in turn bought by Symantec) and the software was discontinued in 2002.  So the scripting language I used, [ASPECT](http://www.aspectscripting.com/index.shtml), just isn't being used anymore.  So there are no questions about it and no tags that I can use in the "Technologies" field.  ([aspect](/questions/tagged/aspect) seems to be a grabbag of junk; much of it relates to display or image technology.)

So how do I include this nugget of experience in my Careers profile?

Comment: Why so specific?

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards: It's an actual problem I faced.  As I thought about this as a feature request, I realized it was dumb.  If you want to list a technology with no tag, ask (and self-answer) a couple of questions.

Comment: Because, when I'm looking for talent, I want to find people with experience in dead languages that nobody uses anymore.  Because I'm an idiot.

Comment: @Won't: Latin teachers everywhere are seething in rage as they read that comment.  ;)

Answer (score 3):

Remember that the purpose of a Careers 2.0 profile (and a resume in general) is to connect employers with candidates that meet their needs.  It seems pretty unlikely that an employer will be searching for someone with experience in an essentially dead technology.  So adding the technology to your profile just clutters up the page.

However, if you still want to include it, you have to ask yourself:

### Do you want to use this technology in your new job?

- **Yes** => Ask and answer a few questions with the tag so that you can be the foremost expert on Stack Overflow in the technology.  (As always, be sure the questions are ontopic and look like they are in earnest.)
- **No** => Add some text in the "Responsibilities" field that describe your work with the technology.  List other technologies you used or pick a more general tag like [scripting](/questions/tagged/scripting).

In other words, who are you trying to reach: some poor slob out there who desperately needs his ProComm Plus scripts updated or an employer who uses current technology?

Comment: +1 very good answer but you're missing one point here.  You can make a lot of money if you're the last person on earth who knows ProComm plus and every company desperately needs someone to maintain it.  They're just not going to try to hire you out of a website that fancy-new-buzzword-technology people hang out at.